# @ConversationScoped in non JSF applications

Tags: java, cdi

I am looking at the annotation @ConversationScoped and its tutorials and it seems that it is mostly used with respect to JSF, even in the API doc it is mentioned in relation to JSF. Can it not be used in a non JSF environment/Application.

Comment: It can only be used in a *Seam* application, which by definition is a JSF application.

Comment: @EJP Thanks... I thought the long running conversation was becoming part of java. Also, I have used Seam with JSF, but i have heard that you cna use Spring MVC with Seam as well.